# How to interpret "computable real numbers are not countable, and are complete"?

Tags: computability

On page 12 of this (controversial) polemic

http://web.maths.unsw.edu.au/~norman/papers/SetTheory.pdf

Wildberger claims that

> Even the "computable real numbers" are quite misunderstood. Most mathematicians reading this paper suffer from the impression that the "computable real numbers" are countable, and that they are not complete. As I mention in my recent book, this is quite wrong. Think clearly about the subject for a few days, and you will see that the computable real numbers are not countable, and are complete. Think for a few more days, and you will be able to see how to make these statements without any reference to "infinite sets"...

These claims are false, as far as I can tell, with the usual definitions. Is there a reasonable way to interpret them---more specifically, do they become true after replacing "countable" by "computably enumerable" and doing something similar with "complete", requiring only sequences that are "computably Cauchy" (feel free to modify my provisional definition below if convenient) to converge? I know nothing about computable real numbers, so I will appreciate it if you are gentle!

Provisional definition: A sequence $a_n$ is *computably Cauchy* if there is a computable function $f: \mathbb{Z}_{> 0} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{> 0}$ such that $|a_k-a_m|<1/n$ if $k,m \geq f(n)$.

Comment: But computable numbers are countable... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_number

Comment: @Dave, you're quite right, of course, and if you read my question you will see that that is the point.

Comment: I think the question here is: can we do math *without* the Axiom on Infinity?

Comment: @Ferdinand.kraft, No, that is most definitely *not* my question. I just want to know if the computable reals are computably complete (I am pretty sure they are not computably enumerable).

Comment: We can say that the computables are incomplete because there exist non-computable Dedekind cuts – see the 4th paragraph of this section http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_numbers#Properties.  Other than that, you'll have to be specific about what you mean by "computably complete".

Comment: @Steve, sorry, I meant the question the *author* poses. He kind of advocates a "set theory" in which axioms are implicit, naively thought to be "obvious", and where an infinite set has no role, just like an "all-seeing leprechaun".

Comment: @Steve it is quite clear the article you cite is, hmmmm, not well-founded (if it were it would not need such 'arguments' as "think for a couple of days and ..."). So, perhaps it is best to avoid referring to it in your question since your question is about computable reals. Before you question can be answered, you will need to tell us what does it mean for the computable reals to be computably complete. Once definitions and (oh yes) axioms are set in place, questions can be asked ans (sometimes) answers can be given.

Comment: Well, it seems to me like most of the paper makes sense if you define "mathematics" as something like "the study of the behavior of computer programs"—*real* computer programs, running on actual computers, not on Turing machines. Adjusting other terms appropriately, the computable real numbers are "uncountable" in a sense (you can't write a computer program that lists each one exactly once), and "complete" in a sense (since all we're talking about is computer programs, we're denying the existence of uncountable real numbers). I have no idea if this is what Wildberger actually had in mind.

Comment: All, don't take this the wrong way: I understand that Wildberger rubs people the wrong way. I would really appreciate it if you would not take it out on me. I asked a precise mathematical question. If you feel it requires more clarification, I will be happy to clarify it.

Comment: To try to (roughly) justify the statement, perhaps he means that the computable reals are not 'countable' in the sense that there's no computable bijection between integers and computable reals?  As long as you're working _within_ the world of computability (and not looking from the 'outside view') then it makes sense to take a computable definition of countability too, and 'has a computable bijection with the integers' seems a legitimate definition of countability that would make the initial statement make sense.

Comment: @Ferdinand.kraft, OK, I see---thanks for the clarification. I disagree with your characterization of his views. Rather, he'd prefer to use definitions in place of axioms. In the daily practice of mathematics, I don't see much difference---either way, to know that you're not doing something vacuous you have to construct a model. It certainly would be safer (though for some, also more boring) never to assert the existence of an infinite set. I have to admit that I don't care much either way. It wouldn't change my mathematical life one bit.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki, Yes, I agree.

Comment: @IttayWeiss, I believe I edited the question to add a precise definition of computably Cauchy sequences nearly simultaneously with your comment. Do you think it is clear now? As for the rest, I respectfully disagree---according to the FAQ, I'm *supposed* to provide motivation. I don't particularly like Wildberger's writing style, either, FWIW: I would prefer a more measured tone.

Comment: I don't think this question should be closed. The question seems precise enough to allow further good answers. That (part of) the motivation comes from a text responsible for a lot of controversy does not seem to be reason enough to close this.

Comment: Thanks @Martin for your kind words; anyway at this point it looks to have a perfectly good answer so it makes little difference if it is closed or not. I have to admit I am curious about the reason people have for voting to close---in the absence of explanation, I have to suppose it is simply that they don't like Wildberger's style.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here we have two assertions. Uncountability and completeness.

In the usual set theoretic tradition computable real numbers are countable since there are only a countable quantity of Turing Machines. Funnily, you can show using Cantor's diagonal argument -the same that it is used to show that real numbers are not countable- that this bijection from the natural numbers to the real computable numbers is non-computable. If you have such a computable bijection, you can compute a real number that is not in the range of this computable function by diagonalization.

Thus real computable number are countable, but not effectively countable, i.e. you cannot give a computable bijection from the natural numbers onto the real computable numbers.

About completeness, Specker sequence using the fact that there are recursively enumerable sets that are not recursive/decidable. Take one of those sets $A\subset \mathbb{N}_1$, and consider an enumeration of it given by
$$a:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow A$$
And so consider the number
$$S_A=\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\frac{1}{2^{a(n)}}$$
Then this number is the supremum of the family of computable numbers $\{S_{A,n}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, where $S_{A,n}$ is given by
$$S_{A,n}=\sum_{i\leq n}\frac{1}{2^{a(i)}}\text{,}$$
but $S_A$ is not computable. (If it were computable, then $A$ would be recursive.) Thus we don't have completeness natural sequences of computable numbers.

However, in the previous example we cannot say that everything is done. If we define a computable Cauchy sequence of computable real numbers as a computable sequence of computable real numbers $\{q_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that there is a computable function
$$r:\mathbb{N}_1\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$$
such that for every $n\in\mathbb{N}_1$, for all $i,j>r(n)$,
$$|q_i-q_j|<1/n$$
Then the resulting limit can be shown to be a computable real number, and thus having a sort of computable completeness.

The previous two things are the facts, thus we have some sort of uncountability, if we add the requirement of computability to the bijection, and a sort of completeness, strengthening the requirements of the definition-. This has to be said that are results very similar to those of Bishop's constructive analysis.

The article you linked seems to me one of those people angry with the infinity and that thinks that mathematics have to be limited to what they think is philosophically valid. However, mathematics is free product of our mind (paraphrasing Dedekind) and thus we have to learn to enjoy it in all its forms since all of them gives us a broader view of the subject.

EDIT: For the affirmation that the computable Cauchy sequence $\{q_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges to a computable real number $q$ we only have to give an algorithm (Turing machine) that calculates the binary expansion of this number.

Remember that a number $x$ is computable if there is a computable function
$$f_x:\mathbb{N}_1\rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$$
such that for all $n\in\mathbb{N}_1$,
$$|f_x(n)-x|<1/n$$

Now, given our computable sequence, this fact is translated that we have a computable function
$$f:\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}_1\rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$$
such that for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $i\in\mathbb{N}_1$,
$$|q_n-f(n,i)|<1/i$$

Now, since this sequence is Cauchy computable, we have that there is a computable function 
$$r:\mathbb{N}_1\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$$
such that for every $n\in\mathbb{N}_1$, for all $i,j>r(n)$,
$$|q_i-q_j|<1/n$$

This fact will be essential for showing that the limit is computable in the considered case. Now, using classical analysis to show that for the limit $q$ we have that for every $n\in\mathbb{N}_1$, for all $i>r(n)$,
$$|q_i-q|<2/n$$

In this way, the desired computable function for approximating $q$ is given by
$$h(n)=f(r(4n)+1,2n)$$

Comment: Thanks +1; do you have a reference for the fact about computably Cauchy sequences converging to computable numbers? (Or better, can you give a quick proof?)

Comment: @Steve There is the proof.